# Fabric notified me "STABILITY ALERT" for my iOS app while app is working fine without any crash

Tags: ios, xcode, google-fabric, fabric.io

I got email from fabric that my iOS app has issue and dropping crash free users but when I am testing, app is working fine without any error or crash even I checked twice XCode logs too.

**Here the screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: fabric also provide crash log, file name and line number. click on go to dashboard and check it.

Comment: Here is no crash, if there is crash then only can get that information @NiravKotecha

Comment: You may have a "closed" bug ?

Answer (score 1):

User's question was resolved by support(at)fabric(dot)io. The filter was pre-cached for a previous date which had no crashes. Resetting the filter populated the correct data.